# Subtraction of polygons using polybool in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Here is the code I am using:

```
[temp_matrix(:,1),temp_matrix(:,2)] = polybool('subtraction',xc,yc,xd,yd)

xc = [0.25 0.25 0.75 0.75];
yc = [0.25 0.75 0.75 0.25];

xd = [0 0 1 1];
yd = [0 1 1 0];

figure(1)
hold on

[fd, vd] = poly2fv(xd, yd);
patch('Faces', fd, 'Vertices', vd, 'FaceColor', 'b', ...
  'EdgeColor', 'none')

[fc, vc] = poly2fv(xc, yc);
patch('Faces', fc, 'Vertices', vc, 'FaceColor', 'r', ...
  'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

`xc`, `yc` (red) is within `xd`, `yd` (blue) but the polybool function gives an error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Why?

Comment: What (in heaven) is this code doing? What are you trying to accomplish? What's the application?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of ordering.  This takes the `xd,yd` polygon away from the `xc, yc` one.

```
polybool('subtraction',xc,yc,xd,yd)
```

Since all of the `xc,yc` polygon is within the `xd,yd` polygon, the outputs of `polybool` in this case are empty.  Trying to assign those empty outputs to `temp_matrix(:,1)`, `temp_matrix(:,2)` gives you the error.  Swapping the inputs around will work:

```
[temp_matrix(:,1),temp_matrix(:,2)] = polybool('subtraction',xd,yd,xc,yc);
```

So will using `xor` rather than subtraction:

```
[temp_matrix(:,1),temp_matrix(:,2)] = polybool('xor',xc,yc,xd,yd)
```